# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot relationship between two variables- represented by points regression line. I also want to add two grey panels on this plot as shown in the graphics below. [image]

I wrote the code couple of days back and it was working fine. But suddenly I have started getting error message "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found" at the last step and it is adding grey panels any more. I googled about this problem, tried updating packages, R and restarting it. None of that seem to work.
Here is the code and output for your reference.

```
> # read files
> 
> tpreg1=read.csv("tpreg1.csv", header = TRUE)
> tpreg2=read.csv("tpreg2.csv", header = TRUE)
> tpreg3=read.csv("tpreg3.csv", header = TRUE)
> 
> tpreg1
   t     a
1 22 15.29
2 24 14.87
3 26 14.43
4 28 13.19
5 30 12.69
6 32 10.58
> tpreg2
   t     a
1 22 13.13
2 24 11.47
3 26 10.01
4 28  8.02
5 30  5.81
6 32  3.25
> tpreg3
     t
1 21.5
2 22.0
3 26.0
4 28.0
5 32.0
6 32.5
> 
> # Library 
> library(ggplot2)
> 
> 
> 
> # CS points, regression line, confidence intervals
> tpr <-
+   ggplot(tpreg1, aes(x = t, y = a)) + geom_point(
+     shape = 1,
+     fill = "darkgreen",
+     alpha = 1,
+     color = "darkgreen",
+     size = 1
+   ) + geom_smooth(
+     method = lm,
+     size = 0.5,
+     linetype = "solid",
+     color = "darkgreen"
+   )
> 
> # Scale
> tpr <- tpr +
+   expand_limits(x = c(21.5, 32.5), y = c(-16, 34)) +
+   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
+                      breaks = c(22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32)) +
+   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
+                      breaks = c(-16, -8,  0, 8,  16, 24, 32))
> 
> # Aspect ratio
> tpr<- tpr + theme(aspect.ratio = 0.75)
> 
> 
> # Panel settings
> tpr <- tpr +
+   theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
+   theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
+         panel.grid.major = element_blank())
> 
> # Axes lines and ticks 
> tpr <- tpr +
+   theme(
+     axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
+     axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
+     axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
+     axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
+     axis.ticks.length = unit(.1, "cm")
+   ) 
> 
> tpr
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
> 
> # Panels
> 
> # straight line equations upper and lower limits of the panels
> 
> # lower dark panel, ymin
> func1 = sapply(
+   tpreg3$t,
+   FUN = function(x) {
+     -1 * x + 16
+   }
+ )
> func1
[1]  -5.5  -6.0 -10.0 -12.0 -16.0 -16.5
> # lower dark panel, ymax
> func2 = sapply(
+   tpreg3$t,
+   FUN = function(x) {
+     0 * x + 0
+   }
+ )
> func2
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 
> # upper dark panel, ymin
> func3 = sapply(
+   tpreg3$t,
+   FUN = function(x) {
+     0 * x + 16
+   }
+ )
> func3
[1] 16 16 16 16 16 16
> # upper dark panel, ymax
> func4 = sapply(
+   tpreg3$t,
+   FUN = function(x) {
+     1 * x + 0
+   }
+ )
> func4
[1] 21.5 22.0 26.0 28.0 32.0 32.5
> 
> 
> # Grey filling
> tpr <- tpr +
+   geom_ribbon(
+     data = tpreg3,
+     aes(x = t, ymin = func1, ymax = func2),
+     fill = "grey",
+     alpha = .25
+   ) + geom_ribbon(
+     data = tpreg3,
+     aes(x = t, ymin = func3, ymax = func4),
+     fill = "grey",
+     alpha = .25
+   )
> 
> tpr
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found
```

Could anybody help me find solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial `ggplot()`, you specify that `y = a`. This mapping is forwarded until it is overwritten. When the error occurs, you specify data that does not contain `a` yet `a` is still mapped onto `y`. Try to set `y = NULL` explicitly to overwrite the mapping.

Comment: Thank you so much @mnist,it worked! I tried to know more about this kind of error, but couldn't get easy read. Could you suggest any link which provide simple explaination for this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

As @mnist explains, the aesthetics are inherited from the initial plot specification in `ggplot()`.

A cleaner solution would be to turn the default `inherit.aes = TRUE` to `FALSE` at your subsequent layers of `geom_ribbon()`, i.e.:

```
> tpr <- tpr +
+   geom_ribbon(
+     data = tpreg3,
+     aes(x = t, ymin = func1, ymax = func2),
+     fill = "grey",
+     alpha = .25,
+     inherit.aes = FALSE
+   ) +
```